# How to Compare 2 Patent data

Tags: patent-infringement, patent-applications, design-patent, patent-services, espacenet

I have a question How to compare Patent data like if we compare the patent data of the 2000 to 2016 it will show us how much technology has been used in these years.

**Compare 1**
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/039827827/publication/US2008249942A1?q=US2008249942A1

**Compare 2**
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/039827827/publication/US2008249942A1?q=US8892471B2

The above patent data belong to the same Family.

Comment: I’m sorry, but it is unclear what you are asking for. Are asking about the difference between the same patent or application between two years or between two technology areas?

Comment: Hi thank you. Difference between the same patent family like one patent is published in 2007 and the other is 2011 so how can i compare it like what changes has been done in these years.

Comment: Typically, the only thing that changes between an application and the resulting patent is the claims.

Comment: You will not see how technology has changed. Once a patent application is filed no new matter can be added so a later version of the application can not show any new technology.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that changes between an application and the resulting patent is the claims.  No new matter is allowed to be added to an application after submission. I suppose there might be the ability to correct misspellings or grammer, but not content. In the case of the linked documents, the application is identical but if you click on the "Family" tab you can link to the issued patent [US8892471B2](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/039827827/publication/US8892471B2?q=US8892471B2). If you check the claims, you will see that there are changes from the application. This is normal as applications usually attempt to cover the broadest scope possible and patent examiners reject overly broad claims and negotiate to narrower ones.